# XSD: Allow set of elements in any order, but also allow unknown elements, if they have different name than the set of defined elements

Tags: xml, xsd

My use case is the following: we have a XSD, which allows only a set of elements in any order. This is the set of elements, which we use in our program. The actual XML is provided by an external party. The format is controlled by the external party as well and they want to be able to extend the format without forcing code changes on our side (updated XSD). Therefore we want to use a XSD, which validates the format as of today, but allows to add additional elements, if they don't have the same names as the ones explicitly defined.

Our attempt was to use a sequence of elements to define the "known" elements and add an xsd:any statement at the end. However, this any statement also allows to specify elements with the same names as our "known" elements. This is not acceptable in this use case, because these known elements must occur at most once.

We are aware that in order to allow any order of the known elements we need to include all order permutations in the XSD. But there are solutions for this on stackoverflow. I am only mentioning this as constraint.

Our attempt (stripped to a minimal example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="MainElement">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="A" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="C" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element name="D" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element name="E" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:any minOccurs="0" processContents="skip"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This XSD accepts the following XML (desired):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
  <MainElement>
    <A>1</A>
    <B>2</B>
    <C>3</C>
    <E>4</E>
    <Unknown>10</Unknown>
  </MainElement>
  <MainElement>
    <A>1</A>
    <B>2</B>
    <D>3</D>
    <E>4</E>
  </MainElement>
</Root>
```

But also this XML is valid, which is not acceptable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
  <MainElement>
    <A>1</A>
    <B>2</B>
    <C>3</C>
    <E>4</E>
    <A>5</A>
  </MainElement>
</Root>
```

How can I add a restriction that only allows additional XML elements, which have a different name than the set of specified elements in the XSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in XSD 1.1 using `xs:any/@notQName` to disallow particular names.

I don't think it can be done in XSD 1.0.

Comment: I am using Microsoft's .NET Framework, which does not seem to support XSD 1.1. I will have to search for a 3rd party validator, which is acceptable for this project. But the original question is answered. Thank you for your help.